# buildozer apk doesn't load gifs (as jpg in zip files)

Tags: android, python-2.7, zip, kivy, buildozer

It's my first kivy app. It shows a different image based on date. My app run perfectly on windows but, in buildozer apk, gifs (as jpg in zip files) are replaced by white squares. Same issue with kivy launcher.
Added zip format in source.include_exts and added pil requirement in buildozer.spec but nothing seems work. Zips are in the right path (indeed they are shown on pc).
My app code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from kivy.app import App
from random import random, randint,choice
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
import datetime
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'butto.png'
        self.size_hint = (0.3, 0.3)
    def on_press(self):
        self.source = 'pressed.png'
    def on_release(self,*args):
        self.source = 'butto.png'

class exitt(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(exitt, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'exit.png'
    def on_press(self):
        self.source = 'bluext.png'
    def on_release(self,*args):
        self.source = 'exit.png'

class killbtn(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(killbtn, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'killbtn.zip'
    def on_release(self,*args):
        self.source = 'killbtn.zip'



class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        my_box1 = FloatLayout()
        bubine = ['a','b']
        frasi=['a','b']
        bubilist= choice(bubine)
        buongglist=choice(frasi)
        my_label1 = Label(text="[color=ff3333]%s, %s![/color]" %(buongglist,bubilist),size_hint_y= .9, text_size=(330, None),halign= 'center', height=self.size[1],line_wrap=True, font_size='24dp', markup= True,pos_hint= {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.77})
        my_button1=MyButton()
        my_button1.size_hint=(.6, .35)
        my_button1.pos_hint= {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3}
        my_button1.bind(on_release=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(.5, .5, .9, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(size=self.update_rect)
    def update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
    def my_callback(self,dt):
        App.get_running_app().stop()
    def changer(self,*args):
        legg=open('gg.txt', 'r')
        ultimogg=legg.readline()
        legg.close()
        oggi=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d')
        if ultimogg==oggi:
            kill= killbtn()
            kill.bind(on_press=self.uccidi)
            popup = Popup(title='Kill.',content=kill,size_hint=(.75,.75))
            popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.my_callback)
            popup.open()
        else:
            self.manager.current = 'screen3'
    def uccidi(self,*args):
        zipcaso=randint(1001,1013)
        load_zipped_png_files = Image(source = 'GIFS/%s.zip'% zipcaso,anim_loop=1,anim_delay = 0.1,keep_ratio = False,keep_data = True,size_hint=(1,1))
        popup = Popup(title='Cosi impara.',content=load_zipped_png_files,size_hint=(.75,.75))
        popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.my_callback)
        popup.open()


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenThree,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        my_box1 = FloatLayout()
        oggi=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d')
        if oggi=='23'or oggi=='14'or oggi=='26' or oggi=='01':
            mese=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')
            if  oggi=='23' and mese=='07':
                numoggi = 'luglio'
            elif  oggi=='14'and mese=='02':
                popup = Popup(title='Buon',content=Label(text='Hello world'),size_hint=(.75,.75))
                popup.open()
                numoggi = 'febbraio'
            elif oggi=='26' and mese=='08':
                numoggi = 'agosto'
            elif oggi=='01' and mese=='01':
                numoggi = 'gennaio'
        else:
            legg=open('numimg.txt', 'r')
            ultimogg=legg.readline()
            legg.close()
            if ultimogg=='1004':
                numoggi=1001
            else:
                numoggi=int(ultimogg)+1
            file = open('numimg.txt','w') 
            file.seek(0)
            file.write(str(numoggi)) 
            file.close()
        file = open('gg.txt','w') 
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(oggi) 
        file.close()
        if numoggi>1019:
            miraglio = Image(source = 'IMMAGO/%s.zip'% numoggi,keep_ratio = False,keep_data = True,size_hint=(1,1))
        else:
            miraglio = Image(source = 'IMMAGO/%s.jpg'% numoggi,keep_ratio = False,keep_data = True,size_hint=(1,1))
        my_button1 = exitt()
        my_button1.size_hint = (0.075, 0.075)
        my_button1.pos_hint= {'right': .97,'top':.97}
        my_button1.bind(on_release=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(miraglio)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)
    def changer(self,*args):
        App.get_running_app().stop()



class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'icona.png'
        my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
        my_screenmanager= ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        screen1 = ScreenOne(name='screen1')
        screen3 = ScreenThree(name='screen3')
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen1)
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen3)
        return my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Logcat report this error: 
`I/python (24189): [ERROR ] [Image ] Error loading texture killbtn.zip` .
What am i missing? thanks anyway!

Comment: I experienced the same issue before. Try reducing the fps to something less than 30. Also reducing the total frames may help. Did you try with different gif files?